# How do I get a CGPoint from a touchesBegan event?

Tags: ios, swift

In my AppDelegate, I want to detect when a tap event has been made to the status bar. In order to do so, I need to get the CGPoint from the event. How do I get it from this code?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    let location = // how to get a CGPoint ????

    let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame
    if CGRectContainsPoint(statusBarFrame, location){
        print("Status bar touched")
    }else{
        print("Not touched")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using Swift 2; you could retrieve the tap location as follows:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch
    {
        //The view you would like to get the tap location from.
        let tapPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view) 
        let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame
        if CGRectContainsPoint(statusBarFrame, tapPoint)
        {
            print("Status bar touched")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Not touched")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Giving it a view will return the CGPoint in the context of that view. The status bar will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

A `UITouch` object has a method `locationInView:` that allows you to find the location of a touch in a particular view. From the docs:

> Returns the current location of the receiver in the coordinate system of the given view.
>
> The view object in whose coordinate system you want the touch located. A custom view that is handling the touch may specify self to get the touch location in its own coordinate system. **Pass nil to get the touch location in the window’s coordinates.**

So try:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }

    let location = touch.locationInView(nil)

    let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame
    if CGRectContainsPoint(statusBarFrame, location) {
        print("Status bar touched")
    } else {
        print("Not touched")
    }
}
```

This works regardless of device orientation

Comment: In this particular case would you have to worry about the orientation of the window itself?

Comment: Seemed to work in Landscape.. I'll test it in Portrait

Comment: Okay, I remember working with the window in an earlier version of iOS and I had that issue sadly. Just checking.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.1

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }

    let location = touch.location(in: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have a view that you touched. If you've managed to get your app delegate to receive touch events, you could try getting the locationInView: using the app delegates window.

Comment: You can pass in nil to use the window's coordinates. You don't necessarily need the view.

Comment: Yeah, I was just suggesting getting the information from the windows coordinates. I should probably make that look like a method instead of words.